# Rendering smoke in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I am trying to render smoke in cycles, but the relevant blender [manual page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Smoke) is designed for Bender Internal. I have everything set up except for the material.

I imagine you would set up the material nodes something like this:

[image]

But the problem is that there is no Voxel Data texture node, ans I am not sure what kind of shader should be used.

Is smoke in Cycles simply not supported yet? Or do I need to go about this a different way?

Reference: [Smoke material in blender internal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Smoke/Material)

Comment: For now you can fake it with motion blur using [this method.](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279752-cycles-hack-volume-lighting/)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/creating-volumetric-lighting-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles

Comment: You can do it now in 2.71 :) "Blender 2.71 Feature Preview: Smoke and Fire in Cycles" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Cycles Roadmap](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap):

> Probably the first release with Volumetrics will be 2.69 or 2.70.

Comment: "Probably" being a keyword - though I can say with certainty that it will not be in 2.69, and I doubt there'll be anything for 2.70 either.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Smoke is supported in cycles starting with version 2.71. It is still limited to CPU rendering (as of version 2.76)

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77

Answer (score 23):

As of version 2.73 from 2015:

- Make sure render engine is set to cycles (BI wouldn't create the required cycles materials)
- Select the object you want to emit smoke
- From the menu *Object/Quick Effects* pick *Quick Smoke*

After that a material has been created that looks like:

[image]

In order to also emit flames it can easily be extended to:

[image]

Note that the attribute names have to be exactly as they  are show 'color','density' and 'flame'.

Important settings for the Domain object (besides higher-resolution):

[image]

Important settings for the *Flow Object*:

Add a procedural texture and animate some properties to animate the flames.

[image]

Full tutorial: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in Blender 2.71 or newer (which added support for volumetric data in Cycles).

Make a group in nodes that looks like on the screenshot below.
It's very important that you make the two "Attribute" nodes exactly like shown on the screenshot - "flame" lowercase and "density" lowercase - because it refers to data in the object.

[image: node group screenshot]

The material itself:
[image: material screenshot]

Now use this material on smoke domain. That's all :)

I took this setup from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs

Answer (score 2):

Volumetrics and smoke are not currently supported by Cycles. There are some experimental builds that will support rendering static volumes, but not voxels, yet.

Version 2.70 is [reported](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/blog/527-demo-volume-with-blender-cycles.html) to support volumes, and voxels (for smoke) will come later.

Comment: It might be clearer to say that the development version of blender as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB01df756bd10709bb707d4f88f14c50e5680d05a5) cycles has volumetric scattering support, and that it will be in 2.70.

Comment: Ah yes, quite right.

Comment: blender 2.73: voxels can now be rendered with cycles (CPU) and static volumes can be rendered with GPU and CPU

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77