# Creating volumetric lighting (crepuscular rays) in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

[Crepuscular rays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_rays) (a.k.a. "god rays" and many other names) can be created in Blender Internal by checking the *Halo* checkbox in the lamp properties box.

How can I create a similar effect using Cycles?

Comment: I don't think this is possible currently. This should be possible once volume render is integrated in 2.69 or 2.7

Comment: It is possible, the question is, for what effect do you need it? I don't know atm if 'light through clouds in the distance' will be pretty, but simulating halos is possible.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/how-to-use-the-volume-socket-in-cycles

Comment: Actually I just need a simple way to visualize a coded light source (something like structured light coded light grey patterns). I would like to create a coned light source that is masked by another object, and light can only pass through the slits.

Comment: @Mercury I'm not sure I understand.. you will still need volumetrics if you want to see the light in the air.

Comment: @gandalf3: you are correct. my question is if there is a way to do it although it is not possible(yet) in cycles, as I don't need somthing very complex...

Comment: @Mercury See [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2555/599). I have listed some ways that I know of to fake this in cycles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Update

As of Blender 2.70, cycles has had volumetric support. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8015/599) for details on how to set up crepuscular rays with the new volumetric features.

---

As mentioned by Wchargin, this will be possible once volumetrics is integrated.

However, there are some ways to fake this:

- [Using motion blur](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?279752-cycles-hack-volume-lighting):

  > Basically you use a plane that moves through the entire scene
  >   perpendicular to the camera, then turn on motion blur and increase the
  >   frame blending enough so that cycles is calculating the entire motion.
  >   The plane will catch the light and blend it through the whole scene
  >   giving the illusion of volume lighting. I used a mix of diffuse and
  >   translucent material for the plane but wouldn't be surprised if there
  >   was a better material method.
- [*Using BI to render halo volumes and then use compositing nodes to combine with Cycles render*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuzDtirK2qk)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Sun Beams node in the Compositor, introduced with Blender 2.72.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Compositing

it doesn't involve true volumetrics and renders super fast, although it's not as flexible and thus not suitable for all situations. Here is a simple example:

[image: sun beams node]

Comment: What is this Add node? I can't find it :/ the one from Math doesn't look the same

Comment: It's under Compositor nodes Color > Mix

Answer (score 7):

The term you're looking for is **[volumetric lighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_lighting)**, an [alternative name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_rays#Alternative_names) for crepuscular rays. Unfortunately, Cycles does not yet support volumetric lighting.

For more info, check out the [Cycles Roadmap](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap):

> For 2.68, the following features are planned to be worked on:
>
> - Hair shader
> - Ubershader (combined diffuse+glossy+transparent node)
> - Look into of improvements for SSS, AO, mist, ..
>
> After this the next big feature will be Volumetrics. **Probably the
>   first release with Volumetrics will be 2.69 or 2.70.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>