# Why doesn't an Environment texture appear when the world has a Volume Scatter shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm working on lighting a scene in which I need to have both an Environment texture for the background and Volume Scatter for light cones, but when I check the volume section in *World* setting and choose the *Volume Scatter*, the environment becomes black background (*but the lighting works as I want*).

*I'm using Blender 2.72*

How can this be fixed?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics It says cycles in the tags quite clearly

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13814/599

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/materials/volume.html?highlight=volume%20world#volume-world), and it's not exactly a bug.

Because the world background is an infinite distance away and a world volume shader is assumed to be infinitely large, there is a bit of a problem. No matter how low the density of the volume is, it will completely absorb all light going an infinite distance through it.

### The solution

You can use a finite object volume instead of an infinite world volume.

To do this, create a largish cube object or any shape which encloses your entire scene (or at least the part which should have fog/mist/whatever in it).

By adding a volume shader to this object, you can create a finite volume around your scene which you have much more control over. See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13814/599) for more detail.

Comment: I can't still get it to work,here is what I'm doing: I add this Cube that contains my scene, then i apply volume scatter and environment texture to volume and surface of this cube.

Comment: @Shanty The cube shouldn't have anything in its surface output. It's fine having a world background that is infinitely far away, the problem is having an infinitely large volume.