# Renderlayer with different world settings?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, world

is it possible to have a renderlayer with different world settings? 
In my current case I would like to have a separate renderlayer to create a volume light. Thus I need to create a volume world shader, but then all renderlayers are affected (and they should use another world shader)

What is the workflow for that? It feels strange that I can't have different world settings per renderlayer...
Thx

Comment: If you are using volume scattering and/or volume absortion create a domain object. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49893/rendering-environment-pass-without-combined-pass-in-cycles/49923#49923 and also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh

Comment: Alright, this is probably going to work.... but in the case of just wanting to have a different hdri per renderlayer, that is currently not possible, is it? thx

Comment: maybe related (?): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403