# Using Transparent Background with Volume Scatter

Tags: volumetrics

everyone. I need your help with. I'm trying to use the Volume Scatter feature with a transparent background in Blender Cycles. I have transparency turned on if that's what you are wondering,but every time,the background isn't transparent like I want it to be. Please help!

I hope that this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/88383/edit) your question by adding an example of the result you are getting, and describing how it is not like you expected?

Comment: If you are using volume scatter in the world's volume you won't be able to do what you want. You need to create a mesh around the scene ( Actiong like a domain) and use the volume scatter on it. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49923/1853

Comment: I finally figured it out. You have to use a cube and turn on the Shadow Catcher feature. It'll make the background transparent while at the same time creating realistic shadows and making the Volume Scatter transparent as well.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK please write an answer detailing what you did, so that others with a similar question can learn from your experience.

Comment: Nice, you found a new use for the shadow catcher! Like cegaton said, this deserves an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get a transparent background while using Volume Scatter. Easy to say that it was purplexing as Edward Nigma's riddles,it finally came to me. The answer to this giant enigma which has puzzled me for months.

The first thing you do is create a plane and enlarge it to surround your camera. The next step is to extrude the plane above your camera. I personally did this step by extruding to Z: 8.00000. Finally,you enable the Shadow Catcher in the object settings and press Shift+LMB to view the object and Shadow Catcher scene at the same time.

Render the scene with Volume Scatter with the Shadow Catcher scene,then the Shadow Catcher background will be transparent. I hope my answer will help those later in the future.