# Volume Scatter in World makes the sky turn black

Tags: volumetrics, world, render-passes

While using the "Volume Scatter" option in Blender the Background turns Black. (I am using Blender 2.79). Here is my issue in detail.

The first image below shows a normal scene with Blue sky (Set using the "World" as shown in the image)

[image]

I wanted to add mist to the scene; so i used the Volume Scatter shader and plugged it into the "Volume" node in the "World Output". The entire scene turned black and later I discovered this feature doesn't work with the "Sun Lamp" well. So I added a "Point Lamp" too in the scene. Now the mist appears. But the issue is that the blue background has entirely turned into black as shown in the image below.

[image]

I've tried changing the Strength of the "Point Lamp" but it won't help. I would request to kindly inform if anyone knows how to fix this.

Comment: You can't use volume scatter and a color background at the same time. Use a domain with volume scatter around the scene. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49923/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Blatant Quote from the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/volume.html?highlight=volume%20world#volume-world))

> **Volume World**
>
> A volume shader can also be applied to the entirely world, filling the entire space.
>
> Currently, this is most useful for night time or other dark scenes, as the world surface shader or sun lamps will have no effect if a volume shader is used. This is because the world background is assumed to be infinitely far away, which is accurate enough for the sun for example. However, for modeling effects such as fog or atmospheric scattering, it is not a good assumption that the volume fills the entire space, as most of the distance between the sun and the earth is empty space. For such effects it is be better to create a volume object surrounding the scene. The size of this object will determine how much light is scattered or absorbed.

To illustrate this workaround: create a box around the scene (it will cat as a domain) and have that box use volume scatter:

[image]

Please note that the volume scatter is plugged to the **volume** socket of the material for the domain, the surface socket should not be used.