# How to make volumetrics work

Tags: light, lighting, volumetrics

I've been reading a lot about this, but I can't find the solution. Anything I've tried so far hasn't helped at all to solve my problem.

The scene is simple. There's a sun light outside which is blueish because this is gonna be a night time scene. I need a volumetric (god-ray like) light coming through the window. In the screenshots you can see my settings.

In order to use the sun light for this, I created a box that surrounds my scene and I've made the volume scatter material for it. I read that .1 is a good place to start at, but it makes my scene completely black. If I get to .001 I can see but I don't really think it creates any volumetric light.

[image]

[image]

I tried both a 1cm sun and a 1m sun, but nothing changes. sun strength at 50,000. I tried even more nothing changes and it seems stupid for me that I have to go higher to make this work, because I 've seen a lot of people working with much less and it works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try increasing transparency bounces in Properties editor > Render tab > Light Paths panel. Note also to use more than 1 bounce for lamp settings

Comment: I tried but nothing changes apparently

Comment: Are you using glass in the windows?

Comment: yes I am using glass

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/volumetric-lighting-has-flopped

Comment: even by moving the glass away (it's a different piece from the window), It's still very dark.