# God Rays through window pane: Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, volumetrics

I'm creating a scene for a project and I wanted to go for the god ray effect achieved by the lights passing through the window. I added a mesh onto which volume scatter node was added, but still, even after fiddling with the volume scatter density, the desired effect couldn't be achieved. Also, the outline of the mesh on which the volume scatter node was applied is visible. For the environment, I used sky texture, and even after using a sun lamp, the results remain the same.
I use blender 2.90 and use the sun disk feature to light the environment. when setting the sun elevation to a specific degree, while rendering it automatically changes.

Heres a picture of the look that I'm going for (got it from blender guru tutorial)

[image]

and here's the render result of my project (ignore the noise)

[image]

Comment: for those looking for a duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/volumetric-lighting-not-showing-very-well/111194#111194

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a cuboid to surround the scene, and use a volume scatter node as volume. Nothing shoud be connected to the surface socket.

The default value of 1 for volume scatter is way too dense for practical use, so use a much smaller value.

[image]

Add a point light and make it very small (in this example is 0m) and very, very, very bright. The smaller the light, the more defined the shadows will be.

[image]

If you are using a glass material for the windows, you have to modify it so that it let's direct light go through it.

[image]

For more info on the glass shader read:

[How to illuminate the dark areas behind glass in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2565/92768)

As for the noise... use a lot of samples.

[image]

Comment: Thank You So Much!!!!!!!! The node setup for the glass shader helped execute the trick. I didn't add the light path node before, now the scene looks perfect. Thank You so Much. Is there any way to gradually decrease the god ray fall off? is it using the Anisotropy value of the volume scatter applied onto the cube?

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/582-cycles-volume-scatter.html. For a falloff you might want to try adding texures to control the color and or density of the volume scatter. further info: https://www.creativeshrimp.com/volumetric-lighting-blender-tutorial.html

Comment: Anisotropy might not be the way to control fall off,  but should be done on the light, or via a volume absorption node.