# How can I make a sunset?

Tags: lighting

Ive been making a warehouse and the lighting is supposed to be like a sunset, but how can i do this and make it look nice?[image]

Comment: I'd recommend just grabbing an HDRI  background off the Internet. There's plenty of free ones to choose from.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Thanks for the tip, but i would like there to be light rays falling in from the window, and i havent found out how to do that with a skyhdr and the rays without it being solid black

Comment: You could have visible air inside the room but not outside of it.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Thats pretty much what I'm looking for, Any idea how?

Comment: You want an object with a volume shader to hold the air, then tweak the density to determine how much light is captured.

Comment: I have a cube set up with colume scatter, is that what can hold the air? And which kind of light source can I use, because with a skyhdr it turns everything black

Comment: read: [Rendering Environment pass without Combined pass in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49893/rendering-environment-pass-without-combined-pass-in-cycles) and [Atmospheric Lighitn in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154) and [HDRI with volumetric Scattering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112513/hdri-with-volumetric-to-create-throw-pattern/112518#112518)

Comment: @cegaton Thanks alot for the info, I'll see how far I can get