# How to set Sun beams and mist in the compositor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, filmic-blender

I appear to be having some issues with setting up both Mist and Sun Beams for cycles in Blender 2.8. I'm attempting to to get a god ray/fake-volumetric effect from the window in my scenes. However, it doesn't appear that the rays or mist are being calculated correctly. It's supposed to look like a beam of light coming through the windows, now it just looks like a muddy mess!

[image]

Here is an example of what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here is the blend file as well if this helps any:

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JN1R8uMn88aA5698H7xNwwiubPwbkwb/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using an HDRI map to light the scene.

This is the node set-up I'm trying to go for:

[image]

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you using a mist pass? Mist will no give you volumetrics. Are you dealing with volume scattering? If so, are you using it in the world or as a domain?  Or are you referring to the compositor? Show images of your settings.

Comment: Use a domain for volume scatter around your scene. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBw3h.jpg

Comment: Duplicate of: [HDRI with volumetric throw pattern](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112513/hdri-with-volumetric-to-create-throw-pattern)

Comment: I added my node set-up that I am trying to use. I want to avoid using volumetrics as much as possible to avoid increasing render times. I used the same set-up on another project and it worked great. I guess the only difference is I didn't use an HDRI set-up in that one.