# Volume Scatter in Cycles Turning world black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I am working on creating a sunset and am having trouble getting the volume scatter node to not turn the entire world black. I have already tried numerous suggestions from other posts including checking that my light source is not a sun-light, checking that the light's power was high enough, and that I have plugged the volume shader into the volume, not the surface input. Despite this, the volume scatter turns the world black. Interestingly, it does this if the density is anything but 0 (e.g. 1.0 ^ 10^-7 still gives a black world). [image: solid mode viewport]
[image: render mode viewport]
I have attempted to use a cube encompassing the scene as well, however I have been unable to make that work. Nevertheless, on a matter of principle, I'd like to get this to work because I can do it in a normal scene without the rest of my objects in it, it is something in this specific file preventing it from working.

Comment: You can't use volume and surface simultaneously in the world. Use a mesh that surrounds the scene and have that one have the volume.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49893/rendering-environment-pass-without-combined-pass-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh