# Volume scatter makes the render image and render view entirely black

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I want to use fog in blender cycles, but I don't understand the mist thing (I am a beginner). I have seen a tutorial on YouTube about volume scatter, but when I apply it, the render view and the rendered image are nothing but black. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Density of 1.0 is waaaaay too high, as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 4):

When you give your environment a Volume Scatter shader, you need to use a light source other than a Sun Lamp, like a Point Lamp or a Plane with an Emission shader. A Sun Lamp essentially lights a scene from an infinite distance away. The light has to go through an infinite amount of space before it reaches your objects in your scene, and so a Volume density of anything greater then 0 will completely block the Sun's rays, since the Sun is an infinite distance away. So you have to use a light source that has a definite location, like a Point Lamp, Spotlight, or Emission shader.

If you must use a Sun Lamp as your light source, instead of giving your whole environment a Volume Scatter shader, create a Cube or Sphere and give that a Volume Scatter, and just scale it up so it encompasses the visible area of your scene. That way a Sun Lamp can penetrate through the fog, since it only has a finite distance the light has to go through.

Comment: As noted by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the default value for scattering (1.0) is indeed to high. Use a smaller value (0.1 would be a good starting point). Additionally, the light sources will seem darker due to the scattering, so be ready to bring up the values for strength.

Comment: One more thing... if you use volume scattering in the world, that invalidates the settings used for surface. So the sky texture will have no effect. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154