# Render layers and volumetric scattering

Tags: render-layers

when I try to render separate layers I have no transparent background reason for volumetric scattering.
is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

*Could you be a more specific? Attach simplified blend file with issue via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Add screenshot with highlighted issue and ideally some reference how should it looks like for you fixed? Thank you*

---

Here is something that seems to be working ... not perfect, but hard to say what is your story.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really need the black background in the world surface? Once you add volume, the surface is ignored. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/why-doesnt-an-environment-texture-appear-when-the-world-has-a-volume-scatter-sh

Comment: @susu Sure I dont ... in this case (black like black). But I cant confirm envi is ignored with volume, even argument in your link make a sence, Volume in eevee world is not infinite it has start 0,1 m / end 100m by default in Render Properties. Here test with envi texture https://imgur.com/kpDTXKb so very low density and Anisotropy with 0,9x works as light catcher in "empty" space.

Comment: interesting. Thanks for taking the time to explore this.