# Fog reveals alpha from png image

Tags: transparency, image, volumetrics

I am using a tree image (png) with fog. I noticed that the fog is highlighting the alpha from the png image. I am using the True Sky addon for the fog.

How can I remove the alpha highlighting?

[image: alpha with fog issue]

I'm attaching a link to the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5xOY84O2PcxHs0xge06eMgPk7eq-haS/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: i think the main problem is, that you are using jpg images which do not support alpha information (transparancy)

Comment: @Chris No, I'm using the png format

Comment: @Chris I guess that's not the problem, because actually the material setup uses color images for masking etc. and the transparency works if you use a standard background instead of the True Sky addon. But to be honest, Tobi: the sky material is a huge amount of custom nodegroups consisting of custom groups which hold custom nodegroups and so on in multiple hierarchies, it is hard to get an overview what exactly is the problem there. And since this paid addon seems to be the problem this question is off-topic here and you should ask the developers.

Comment: @Chris Okay, thank you. But the thing is that other projects (in which I didn't use the True Sky addon) also had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it in Blender 4 and rendered it with a built in HDRI. The outline issue isn't showing up for me. I'm inclined to think it is the addon as well

[image]

The Screenshot is blurry, but I couldn't recreate the problem.

Comment: As I understand it, you didn't use the fog, the whole problem is in the fog.

Comment: in that case, It would have made sense to have it turned on already in the file you shared.  I don't know what method you were using for fog. Is it global, a volume object, alpha fox, or a post processing method?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the True Sky addon who plugged the volume shader in your world material, or is it you? Because, to my small knowledge, [volumes don't work in world shaders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19227/53447). Could have changed since then, but if True Sky is supposed to make this work, I would definitely check with them.

In the meantime, I suspect that it isn't how it is supposed to work. The usual way to add environment volume like that is to create a containing mesh around where you want the volume. Then add the volume shader to it:

[image]

[image]

I suspect that could be the purpose of your `tVFX-World Sphere` object.