# Cycles smoke always better in viewport compared to render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, smoke-simulation, color

I'm trying to figure out why my renders don't have the same color as my viewport.
When rendering I almost have no color and in the viewport is the result that I'm looking for.

Viewport:
[image]

similar result i have with render (value 1000):
[image]

Rendered view result:
[image]

The only thing I can make it a bit "better" is by setting the multiply node to high values like 300 or 1000.
There is a lamp (sun), but adding a second one doesn't seem to affect it.
Is it maybe my node setup?

Comment: You may need to decrease the step size of the volumetric sample in the scene properties tab to get more samples on it?

Comment: @3pointedit where can I find that step size? I'm at the Scene tab, but I see [Custom Properties], [Preview], [Surface], [Ambient Occlusion], [Ray Visibility], [Settings] but none has step size?

Comment: Heres an example of step size settings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ig30ziA8dAU and they can be found: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MFSb5.png (here is where I found that last image http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/correct-way-to-render-crepuscular-rays-in-cycles)

Comment: thanks, it gets better: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/105078 !

Comment: Unfortunately for us, in Blender "More Samples" fixes most things ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bake the simulation. Click on the smoke domain wile the domain is selected go to the camera  properties tab and scroll down to the bake take. Set your simulation range to the number of frames in your animation and press bake all dynamics (or bake all). Then render and enjoy... Make sure you add emission to the smoke to make it pop a bit!