# Blender Cycles smoke won't render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to add smoke to a cigarette. I've created a Cylinder, hit space and chose quick smoke while this sphere was selected. It created a transparent bigger sphere and it is emitting smoke in solid and texture mode. But when I try it out in render mode, it won't show the smoke for some reason. Here is my setup:

[image: pictures]

The cylinder has a basic white material.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you give the domain a material?

Comment: it has a material, that has no surface or any other shaders.

Comment: Quick smoke should automatically add some volume shaders to the material.. What version of blender are you using?

Comment: Blender version 2.74

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Smoke rendering in Cycles still has a few tricks:

**1-** Quick smoke should have created some default shaders for the **Smoke Domain**, make sure they are there, if not recreate them like this:

[image]

Note that the attributes are written in **lowercase**. Using uppercase will make the materials fail

**2- As of version 2.77 Smoke can be rendered using GPU**

> For **blender versions prior to 2.77** you can only use CPU rendering to be able to see the smoke in render view and in the final render.
>
> [image]

[image]

Rendered Image:

[image]

For a detailed description of nodes for Fire+Smoke on cycles read: [Rendering smoke in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24424/1853)