# Smoke is not appearing in Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I am stuck with a unique problem. I created some smoke per a detailed tutorial. It appears in the viewport but not during rendering with Cycles. I have attached both the snapshots and .blend file. I am using Blender 2.74.

The interesting thing is that even when I tried rendering an already-made smoke scene that I downloaded, it did not render anything on my system. Please help me out.

Blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2piSDHkvL_6cDhoa1g2YV9ieUU/view?usp=sharing

Thanks and Regards Sabin

[image: View port- smoke]
[image: Output in Cycles render - No smoke]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30579/blender-cycles-smoke-wont-render and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles, you can use the node setup ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have not specified any attributes for the two attribute nodes to access.  The one controlling the scatter and adsorption should be using the `density`, this means that the *fac* output will be carrying the density voxel (volume-pixel) data of the smoke simulation.  Similarly the node controlling the emission shader should be using the `flame` attribute (I presume that the emission shader is for the flames).

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. However the actual problem was, I started my work in Blender internal, afterwards switched to Cycles. If you do so you won't be able to see fire in the cycles render. Right from the beginning of the work the render should be Cycles. I hope, this is a small bug in Blender. Anyway thank you putting time to solve my issue.

Comment: PGMath, you saved my life!