# Smoke is not appearing in cycles, neither is the CPU option

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I have v2.75 and I keep seeing that I need to change the render to CPU, but I don't even see the option... How do I fix this so that I can see the smoke when I render it?[image]

Comment: v2.75.4 to be specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blender Cycles smoke won't render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30579/blender-cycles-smoke-wont-render)

Comment: If you don't see the GPU option you are using the default setting, which is CPU.

Comment: CPU is the default, so if your smoke isn't rendering it's likely for a different reason. If the [answer cegaton linked](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30694/599) doesn't solve your issue, perhaps if you could upload your .blend we might determine what the cause is

Answer (score 3):

The CPU/GPU dropdown selection menu is not visible because you don't have an Nvidia GPU card enabled for usage (either your card isn't Nvidia or it's not enabled for rendering) in the user settings. CPU mode is the default render mode in this case.

If you DO have an Nvidia card installed, you may have to update to the newest drivers for it to show up in your CUDA user preferences selection.