# Smoke is not showing up in cycles 2.76 when I try to render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm new to Blender and cannot figure out how to get the smoke to show up when I render.
[image]

Attached is the link to my file...

http://we.tl/1hnJHPvZgE

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Plenty on information here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30579/blender-cycles-smoke-wont-render and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33356/smoke-is-not-appearing-in-cycles-render

Comment: Related links: [1](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33356/smoke-is-not-appearing-in-cycles-render?rq=1) [2](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles?lq=1) (edit: sorry if either of those links are the same as cegaton's - we posted at about the same time)

Comment: @MAK your glass can't be your domain object and have it's own texture. Make a domain object with the proper materials for smoke. Your glass object can then be a collision object to deflect the smoke.

Comment: @MAK in the future try to upload some images that show your settings so that the question stands on its own independent of the link to the file. Also when you upload the file to a service like wetransfer the link is set to expire in a few days making your question impossible to reference by future users. Please use  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I will check these out. And will also use a different upload service. Sorry, I'm new to this!

Comment: The problem I'm sure had something to do with my glass being the domain, but also that I was using GPU and switched to cycles after I started working. Apparently there is a glitch where you have to begin working in cycles or the smoke wont show up. It also wont show up if you are using GPU compute, it has to be CPU.

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77