# Picture projection on smoke simulation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

It's been a little while i'm using Blender now, but I never did try to simulate smoke yet.

I have to work on titles for a little movie and I was wondering if it was possible to make a picture projection on a smoke simulation (using Cycles) and if you had some directions to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: What render engine are you using?  In Cycles I would plug the image into the color of the smoke using *camera* or *window* coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, Cycles... I edited the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a spot light and add an image as texture to it.

[image]

Comment: Holy !   That's nice ! :)

Answer (score 7):

In Cycles (I don't know about BI) you can use the [standard smoke node setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13685/5705) (without the fire nodes) and replace the `color` *attribute* node with an *image texture* node using [*window* texture coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23174/5705).

Here is the render:
[image]

For comparison, here is it using the actual smoke color (before replacing the color attribute node):
[image]

And here are the nodes:
[image]
<sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

If your image has an alpha channel just multiply the `density` attribute node by the alpha channel before giving it to the density of the shaders.

Comment: Thanks PGmath, that's a nice solution but I forget to mention that what I'm looking for is to distort the picture on the smoke mesh (projection), so cegaton's answer is perfect for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Also, have a look at the [UV projet modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html).