# Domain boxes show up in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

So I recently made the switch to cycles rendering and smoke modifiers, but it's been giving me loads of problems already.

This is what the model looks like:
[image: model in viewport]

And then when I go to render it, this is the result I get.

[image: rendered result]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Cycles's material system is different from BI's. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/924/599 for some examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you have a diffuse shader assigned to the surface of your domain.  Make sure that there is nothing (or a pure white *transparent* shader) plugged into the *surface* socket on your domain object, and that the smoke nodes are plugged into the *volume* socket.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, PGmath.
I'm trying to steer clear of nodes for now because they're just way over my head at the moment. I did find an alternate solution for it thanks to your diffuse advice. I went to the materials tab, added a new material, set surface as Transparent BSDF, and set it on pure white. This seems to have done the trick for me, and I thank you for the help on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Problem AMD video cards do not support Smoke or fire rendering, instead of the fire or smoke you will get the domain rendered as a solid object.

Solution:
Switch to CPU only on system preferences, or get an Nvidia video card.

Sadly there is no word on AMD support for Blender Fire and Smoke rendering.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to disable the emitter for particles under the Particle properties tab in viewport display and render (Uncheck show emitter).

For (fog boxes) you should only need to go to the viewport display option in the same tab and set display as Wire or bounds.

Don't know if this works for fire & smoke.

Answer (score -4):

VERY SIMPLE METHOD: Highlight the domain bounding box, then in the scene menu, top right, turn off the little camera icon and it will no longer appear in your render.

Comment: Not a solution. If you do that then you won't get smoke either. The smoke domain needs to be renderable. The materials need to be fixed in a way that only the volume is visible.