# Render View Problem on fire rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, physics

So i was following a "How to make a fire" tutorial on youtube and i have a render view problem now.
[image]

An when i change to render view it looks like this 
[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: Also the same problem: [Smoke is not appearing in Cycles render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33356/2217), and [Domain boxes show up in cycles render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39360/2217)

Answer (score -1):

You can set a transparent material to the domain object (or whatever blocks the light!)

Comment: This isn't correct as it will effectively make all the fire transparent. The solution is to make material for the domain correctly, using **Volume Scattering** and **Volume Absorption** shaders and *Volume* input socket on the material output as in the linked answers done.