# Black Cube instead Quick Smoke in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Just did one tutorial from youtube with colored quick smoke in Cycles and everything goes well and in render view it show me my smoke and i even render it in low quality to look how's it.

After i bake my simulation... Now i can't see what's happened, because i see only BLACK CUBE (smoke domain) and when i start render it just a black cube...

I made this in cycles from the beginning and it's cpu and it used to work fine.  Does someone know what's happening.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you attach the .blend? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Also, please don't use caps that way

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5282" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5282/)

Comment: Nicole, have a look at this question and answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39360/domain-boxes-show-up-in-cycles-render. You have to go to the node editor and change the output from surface to volume (tested it).

Comment: You're welcome :)