# Fire Adaptive Domain rendering like a solid cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, smoke-simulation

When I render I see a solid cube which is Adaptive domain. But it shouldn't show up. I feel like I missed something. It is my first time simulating fire.

*Candle with a solid domain blocking the fire*

[image: viewport render of smoke]

**The material seems to be plugged in to the volume already :/**

*Node setup*

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your nodes for the fire?  It looks like you don't have any, which is you problem if so.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: I can't really upload the file, since I am participating in a competition. I might want to just create everything again from scratch. Just don't want to risk.

Answer (score 3):

You have a material plugged in to the *Surface* for the domain. Because you are rendering a material on the surface of the domain nothing else will show. You need to delete that and add a smoke and fire node set up, which gets plugged in the the *Volume* input.

[image: cycles smoke and fire nodes]
Here is an example smoke and fire node setup for cycles.
The top frame labeled *Smoke* is the default node setup from "Quick Smoke." Which is accessible from the 3D view header then *Object* > *Quick Effects* > *Quick Smoke*.

Briefly, what is happening there is your material is getting the smoke sim data from the *"density"* in the *Attribute* node. That is fed in to the two volume nodes, *Scatter* and *Absorption* which together normally make a completely dense, uniform volume. However with the data from the smoke sim, it changes the density in some parts of the object, making it take the exact shape of the smoke sim.

The bottom frame *Fire* is what is giving the flames the color you will see in the render. Similarly to the density, the *"flame"* in the *Attribute* node is where we get the fire data to add in.
*(Credit goes to Andrew Price for popularizing the use of the ColorRamp node for controlling the color of the fire. Prior to that it was common to use a [black body node](http://loran-cg.blogspot.com/2014/06/blender-271-cycle-fire-and-smoke-shader.html).)*

Then all that gets combined with the *Add Shader* and pluged in to the *Volume* input of the *Material Output* node.