# Smoke Domain casts a large shadow

Tags: smoke-simulation, shadows

[image]I am making an animation in cycles render where there is a smoking object over a desert. There is a large dark spot(which is not the smoke) on the object below. Placing a light source near it helps but does not fix it completely, it is still darker than it should be. Additionally the smoke is black and not grey like I intended. I have included a picture to help to illustrate my problem. To summarize the smoke domain(which I made with quick smoke) is casting a shadow on its own and the smoke is totally black. Thank you very much

John

[image]

Comment: This question needs more info.. like node setup for your smoke. As I tried, Quick smoke domain doesn't give any shadows and it shouldn't because its material should be set to volumetrics (which cast shadow a bit different). See for smoke setup http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24424/1245

Comment: Can you send a image on the node for the fire and domain

Comment: I edited the size but thats it. I made a regular cube and applied the quick smoke effect

Comment: It's hard to tell what is exact reason for that behaviour. What Blender version do you use? Make sure there aren't any other objects casting shadow around there. Redo the Quick Smoke on a new object; in anyway it doesn't and shouldn't behave like that; possibly (but not necessarily) that's a bug. Check what do you use for rendering - CPU or GPU and if the latter then which one. [Upload](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your file to probably get info about your exact case.

Comment: Fixed it! Ambient Occlusion was off for some reason. Thank you all for your help.