# Cycles fire/smoke render - black particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, smoke-simulation

I trying to make jet exhaust for short jet animation, but when i trying to render it, fire and smoke are rendered as black particles.[image: Before render]

[image]

Here's the node setup for the domain material:

[image: scr-original-domain-material]

---

#### EDIT

After I followed instructions to add shaders for the fire I got this result:

[image: scr-edited-domain-material-render]

Here is modified node setup:

[image: scr-edited-domain-material-nodes]

Comment: Please show the node setup for your domain material. It's likely that there isn't any attribute for fire to show which should be `flame`.

Comment: You have right, i didn't change anything in node editor. http://i.imgur.com/MTnQbDe.png

This is first time when i trying to render fire so i dont thought about it.

Comment: To render fire with that material either add shaders as in the linked answer or just after running *Quick Smoke* operator choose *Fire + Smoke* on the Toolshelf in the operator options (note - the latter assumes rebuilding current smoke setup).

Comment: I used nodes from linked question, but still i'm doing something wrong.
Nodes are on Smoke Domain. On cone, which is "flow" i don't have any nodes.
http://i.imgur.com/7mvvojz.png
http://i.imgur.com/1HxAEey.png

Comment: Generated factor for the fire is not used, so it emits all over the volume. Type in `flame` as is described already in the linked question in the [last screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2131.png) (*Attribute* node contents).

Comment: The color ramp for the flame is connected to an attribute node that is not linked to any data. In the blank window type "flame". Also make sure that your emitter object is set to fire+smoke. Related link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424