# Cycles and quick smoke: the fire doesn't show up rendered video

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an animation. It's a space launch vehicle that is moving up, and I've added a quick smoke effect with a square mesh attached to it at the bottom, but when I render it, the fire doesn't show up at all. I can only see the smoke. Are there any particular settings that I should change or add? I rendered it in blender cycles. I would really appreciate if someone out there knows why this is happening or if there are setting that need to be added, or modified.

Thank you,
Mari

Comment: see the node setup in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24424/1853

Comment: after all, it's called quick _smoke_...

Comment: Quick Smoke has options in Last Operator panel (F6).. Change it to Fire+Smoke and quick fire+smoke is ready

Comment: You probably still have to add a Material to the domain object.