# Smoke domain rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I saw a couple of questions here but they are not helping.

This is what I did:

1. Added a circle as emitter.
2. Added a domain cube
3. Changed the desired settings and this is the result in 3D viewport:

[image]

you can see the domain box and smoke. But when I render this scene, I see the domain cube and no smoke.

There are no materials assigned to the emitter and domain. This is my first time with smoke simulation and it is giving me a headache.

Comment: *"There are no materials assigned to the emitter and domain"* and that's why there's no smoke in render. Emitter doesn't need a material while domain does. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24424/1245

Comment: @MrZak I don't know why this was marked as duplicate. My problem was solved differently and that was not shown in any of the answers in that linked post. I also said, "I saw a couple of questions here but they are not helping."

Comment: "I saw a couple of questions here but they are not helping" specify how please. "that was not shown in any of the answers" what was then? "why this was marked as duplicate" I didn't mark. What I can tell from the info you provide is that there aren't any materials on the domain which will mean you need to do exactly what is shown in the linked post. Duplicate can be always reopened if you edit it with enough information showing it's not a duplicate

Comment: @MrZak The materials were assigned at first, but it was not working. I repeated the process 2-3 times and the materials were not assigning. After posting this question, I tried it again and this time it worked.