# Smoke not rendering in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm currently attempting to use a smoke effect to create an animation. the effect is working fine in solid mode but when I go to render view the smoke does not render. I'm not sure why this is, and would appreciate some help on rendering the smoke. Below is the blend file I am working on:

[image]

Comment: This is point #5 on the answer there...please check that post before asking a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Domain's object settings, Ray visibility channel, check the Camera option:

[image: demo pic]

I don't know why you unchecked this, but this options basically determines whether or not the object is rendered in the camera's eyes. So you never uncheck this on something you want to see.

By the way, you may want to check that related question as well: [Rendering Smoke in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles/24424#24424).