# Quick Effects Smoke Rendering as square

Tags: smoke-simulation

I rendered a png file which has appeared as with a box where the smoke should be. There's also a screenshot of the materials setting selected which does show the smoke. Whats going wrong here?

[image]
[image]

[image]

I don't think I have any materials for the emitter? The smoke is created from the quick effects menu.

[image]

Comment: No pictures of your settings for the outliner? or the materials for the emitter? What else can you tell us about the project and how you set the smoke simulation? The more information you share, the easier it is to help.

Comment: Can't also verify that it is Blender!

Comment: sorry here is the program [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6001" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6001/)

Answer (score 0):

You have no material in the smoke domain, so the smoke domain will render as a white box.

[image]

Read the following link to set the materials correctly.

[Rendering smoke in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/924/rendering-smoke-in-cycles)